# Why has everyone on Earth forgotten about the Daleks?

Tags: doctor-who

Ok maybe not everyone but in "Resolution" the Doctor has to explain who the Daleks are despite the fact they have invaded Earth many times over the years, certainly anyone in the UK should be aware of them surely!

Comment: [Related, possible dupe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/196350/58193): It talks in the general sense of "aliens" but I'm sure it'll apply to Daleks equally as well. Will wait for someone more knowledgeable in Doctor Who than me though before casting a close vote.

Comment: Good fine - this quote seems to tbe the canon explanation:-

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/196367/82047

Comment: Another good discussion here - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/117764/82047

Comment: Humankind always forgets in Doctor Who.